# In RxSwift, how can I unit test that an observable sent no event?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, observable, rx-swift

I am new to testing un RxSwift.
I manage to test that an Observable emits values with RxBlocking. But I can't find the syntax to make a test pass if an Observable did not send any value.

I think I should use `toBlocking(timeout: )`,but I can't find how (I have an error that it timed out, but the test fail).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your observable complete? It looks like you're testing to see if the observable emits any `events` not `values`

Assuming you are testing on the XCTest Framework,

1. If you are testing to see if the observable emits no elements before it completes,

```
XCTAssertNil(try observable.toBlocking().first())
```

2. If you are testing to see if the observable does not emit any elements, nor completes

```
// Check error if necessary
XCTAssertThrowsError(try observable.toBlocking(timeout: timeout).first())
```

Comment: Ah yes! I didn't know you could check the type of error with XCTAssertThrowsError. Thank you!